# How to fix MSVCP120D.dll error Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, opencv3.0

I am trying to run a C++ OpenCV 3.0 example in Visual Studio 2015 and I get a system error saying

> The program can't start because MSVCP120D.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I have tried to reinstall Visual Studio but this does not fix the problem. Does anybody have any other solutions I could try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internal version of Visual Studio 2013 is 12. The DLL in question is version 12 (MSVCP**120**D, the D stands for Debug). You probably downloaded OpenCV compiled for Visual Studio 2013.

To use it with Visual Studio 2015 (known also as Visual C++ 14.0) you need to compile against VS 2015 or maybe find a download package pre-compiled for 2015.